# how to rename azure subscription name through powershell

Tags: powershell, azure

i am trying to rename my azure subscription name with powershell

```
Get-AzureSubscription "Visual Studio Professional with MSDN" | Set-AzureSubscription "MSDN"
```

but its not working for me .error is below -

```
Set-AzureSubscription : Cannot bind positional parameters because no names were given.
At line:1 char:64
+ Get-AzureSubscription "Visual Studio Professional with MSDN" | Set-AzureSubscrip ...
+                                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-AzureSubscription], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousPositionalParameterNoName,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Profile.SetAzureSubscriptionCommand
```

Comment: `Set-AzureSubscription` creates a new subscription if the subscription specified as the value to `-Subscriptionname` does not exist. It does not rename an existing subscription.

Comment: the error you are getting is because you did not provide -SubscriptionName parameter.

Comment: do you know the correct command to rename the subscription name ?

Comment: Nope. There is nothing today in the Azure module.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot rename it with PowerShell at the moment.

Here is a list of all supported Azure PowerShell commands related to manage a profile:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn790379.aspx

You can see that there is is no command to change a subscription name. The only command to change a subscription is the Set-AzureSubscription, but it uses the -SubscriptionName parameter as the identifier:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn790376.aspx

So basically, with Set-AzureSubscription you can change all other properties except the name.

Comment: i saw a video in youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0rE6kXvK8J8) , and he was successfully able to rename the subscription from powershell